# Writing major mode: how set different start string and end string character?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing a major mode where I can have multiline strings like this:

```
Text : >abcde
fgh
ijklmonp<
```

where '>' and '<' indicate the respective start and end of the string. The following syntax table entries only mark >...> and <...< strings, which is not what I want.

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?> "\"" st)
(modify-syntax-entry ?< "\"" st)
```

Currently the best solution is using generic string delimiters: ‘|’, but it still messes up my system as I have >...<...< situations sometimes. The best would be if I could use a multiline regexp like

```
^Text : >.*<$
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As thornjad explains, this is not supported directly by syntax-table, so you need to use `syntax-propertize-function`.  E.g.

```
(defconst my-syntax-propertize
  (syntax-propertize-rules
   (">" (0 (unless (nth 8 (save-excursion (syntax-ppss (match-beginning 0)))
             (string-to-syntax "|"))))
   ("<" (0 (when (eq t (nth 3 (save-excursion
                               (syntax-ppss (match-beginning 0))))
             (string-to-syntax "|"))))))
```

then in your major mode function:

```
(setq-local syntax-propertize-function my-syntax-propertize)
```

The `nth 8` test makes sure `>` is only marked as a string delimiter if it is not within another string or comment, and the `nth 3` test makes sure that `<` is only marked as a string delimiter when it occurs with a string that was started by another generic string delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `modify-syntax-entry` isn't powerful enough to handle this sort of situation. Luckily we have other options! My [`orson-mode`](https://gitlab.com/orsonlang/orson-mode) deals with a similar issue where strings are delimited by double-single quotes (`''`) instead of double quotes (`"`).

To do this, a regexp looks for the entire string, quotes included, then uses Emacs's `string-fence` class to mark the quotes as fences.

```lisp
(defconst orson--string-rx
  "\\(''[^']*''\\)")

(defun orson-syntax-propertize-function (start end)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (while (re-search-forward orson--string-rx end 'noerror)
      (let ((a (match-beginning 1))
            (b (match-end 1))
            (string-fence (string-to-syntax "|")))
        (put-text-property a (1+ a) 'syntax-table string-fence)
        (put-text-property (1- b) b 'syntax-table string-fence))))
```

Comment: Note that your code only works for single-line strings :-(

Comment: Totally right, fixed to include newlines (and everything else)

Comment: @thomjad: The problem was not just in the regexp, but in the approach: START...END may be too small to contain the whole string, in which case your `re-search-forward` will fail to notice the string, or it will mis-match (taking a closing `''` for an opening one and the next opening `''` for its matching string close), ...  IOW you really want to match just the delimiters separately.